# How to add "https://www.example.com/" before scraped URLs in Python that don't already have it

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, uri

I'm a rookie using Python and I'm trying to scrape a list of URLs and from a website and send them to a .CSV file but I keep getting a bunch of URLs that are only partial. They don't have "https://www.example.com" before the rest of the URL. I've found that I need to add something like "['https://www.example.com{0}'.format(link) if link.startswith('/') else link for link in url_list]" into my code but where am I supposed to add it? And is that even what I should add? Thanks for any help! Here is my code:

```
url_list=soup.find_all('a')
with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    for link in url_list:
        url=link.get('href')
        if url:
            writer.writerow([url])
f.close()
```

If you notice anything else that should be changed please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `if` statement will achieve this. Just check for the existence of `https://www.example.com` in the URL and if it doesnt exist, concatenate it.

```
url_list=soup.find_all('a')
with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    for link in url_list:
        url=link.get('href')
        # updated
        if url != '#' and url is not None:
            # added
            if 'https://www.example.com' not in url:
                url = 'https://www.example.com' + url
            writer.writerow([url])
f.close()
```

Comment: You're checking in the wrong location which was the OP's question.  You should be validating the `link` variable, not `url`

Comment: @Thomas if the output is that all URLs in the CSV must be complete, then it doesn't matter where you do the validation.

Comment: @Franco That gave me an error. "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

Comment: @Thomas updated the answer to cater for there being an empty `link.get('href')`

Comment: @Thomas it sounds like your `link.get('href')` type isn't a `string`. You can convert it this way `url=str(link.get('href'))`

Comment: it would also be helpful if you could `print(url_list)` and paste the output into the question

Comment: @Franco That worked! It fixed all of the ones I was worried about but now I'm getting a bunch that say "https://www.example.comNone" and a few that say "https://www.example.com#...". Do you have any idea how to get rid of the ones that say "None" or have a "#" in them? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated my answer to cater for the None and # issues but you should you should probably try and debug why you are getting None in the URL field. # exists if the site wanted to send the user to a specific part of the page (e.g. a specific div).

Comment: @Franco I'm still getting both in the results. Does it have anything to do with the 'url=str(link.get('href'))' that I added? A couple of examples are:  
 https://www.example.comNone and https://www.example.com#skipsideNav